# invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript in multidimensional array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

While doing my course project of card game, i got this error 
Invalid types `int[int]' for array subscript'
Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randomize(int, int);
int* generateCardNumber(int[5]);
int* generateCardLogo(int, int[13][4], int[5]);
int* compareCard(int[5], int[5], int[5], int[5], int[13][4]);
int printResult(int[5]);
void showCard(int, int[5], int[5], int[5], int[5]);
void printCard(int[5], int[5]);


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int player1Number[5], player1Logo[5];
    int *number1, *logo1;
    int player2Number[5], player2Logo[5];
    int *number2, *logo2;
    int cardInfo[13][4];
    int **card;
    char answer;

   do
   {
       int playerInput;
       int d, c, r;
       int player1Score, player2Score;
       cout<<"Welcome to the card game!"<<endl;
       cout<<" Choose player{1: Player 1; 2: Player 2} : ";
       cin>>playerInput;
       cout<<endl;

       do
       {
            cout<<"Press d to deal card :";
       }while(d != 'd');
       number1  = generateCardNumber(player1Number);
       logo1    = generateCardLogo(1,cardInfo, player1Number);
       for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
       {
           cardInfo[player1Number[i]][player1Logo[i]] = 1;
       }
       number2  = generateCardNumber(player2Number);
       logo2        = generateCardLogo(2,cardInfo, player2Number);
       for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
       {
           cardInfo[player2Number[i]][player2Logo[i]] = 1;
       }
       showCard(playerInput,player1Number,player1Logo,
       player2Number,player2Logo);

       do
       {
          cout<<"Press c to compare card :";
       }while(c != 'c');
       *card = compareCard(player1Number,player1Logo,
       player2Number,player2Logo,cardInfo);
       for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
       {
           if(cardInfo[player1Number[i]][player1Logo[i]] = -1)
           {
               player1Number[i] = -1;
               player1Logo[i] = -1;
           }
           else if(cardInfo[player2Number[i]][player2Logo[i]] = -1)
           {
               player2Number[i] = -1;
               player2Logo[i] = -1;
           }
       }

       showCard(playerInput,player1Number,
       player1Logo,player2Number,player2Logo);

       do
       {
           cout<<"Press r to show result :";
       }while(r != 'r');
       if(playerInput == 1)
       {
           cout<<"Player1 (You):        ";
           player1Score = printResult(player1Number);
           cout<<"Player2 (Computer):   ";
           player2Score = printResult(player2Number);
           if(player1Score > player2Score) cout<<"You WIN!"<<endl;
           else cout<<"Computer WIN!"<<endl;
       }
       else if(playerInput == 2)
       {
           cout<<"Player1 (Computer):   ";
           player1Score = printResult(player1Number);
           cout<<"Player2 (You):        ";
           player2Score = printResult(player2Number);
           if(player2Score > player1Score) cout<<"You WIN!"<<endl;
           else cout<<"Computer WIN!"<<endl;
       }
       cout<<"Do you want to play again? (y/n)"<<endl;
       cin>>answer;     
   }while(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
}

int randomize (int x, int y)
{
   return (rand()%y + x);
}

int* generateCardNumber (int numberArray[5])
{
    int arrayStoring[13] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            numberArray[i] = randomize(1,13);   
        }while (arrayStoring[numberArray[i]] == 1);
        arrayStoring[numberArray[i]] = 1;
    }
    return numberArray;
}
int* generateCardLogo (int turn, int cardInfo[4][13], int player2Number[5])
{
    int logoArray[5];
    if(turn == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            logoArray[i] = randomize(1,4);
        }
        return logoArray;
    }
    else if(turn == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                logoArray[i] = randomize(1,4);  
            }while (cardInfo[player2Number[i]][logoArray[i]] == 1);         
        }
        return logoArray;
    }   
}

int** compareCard(int player1Number, int player1Logo, int player2Number, int player2Logo, int cardInfo)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5 ; j++)
        {
            if(player1Number[i] == player2Number[j])
            {
                if(player1Logo[i] < player2Logo[j]) cardInfo[player1Number[i]][player1Logo[i]] = -1;
                else if(player1Logo[i] > player2Logo[j]) cardInfo[player2Number[i]][player2Logo[i]] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cardInfo;
}

int printResult (int playerNumber)
{
    int playerScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(playerNumber[i] == -1) break;
        else if(playerNumber[i] == 0)
        {
            playerScore += 15;  
            cout<<"15 ";
        }
        else if(playerNumber[i] > 0 && playerNumber[i] < 10 )
        {
            playerScore += (playerNumber[i] + 1);
            cout<< (playerNumber[i] + 1) <<" ";
        }
        else if(playerNumber[i] >= 10)
        {
            playerScore += 12;
            cout<<"12 ";
        }

        if(i<4) cout<<"+ ";
        else if(i==4)
        {
            cout<<"= "<<playerScore<<" points";
        }
    }
    return playerScore;
}

void printCard (int numberArray[5], int logoArray[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        switch(numberArray[i])
        {
            case -1 :
                cout<<"<fold> ";
                break;
            case 0 :
                cout<<"Ace ";
                break;
            case 1 :
                cout<<"2 ";
                break;
            case 2 :
                cout<<"3 ";
                break;
            case 3 :
                cout<<"4 ";
                break;
            case 4 :
                cout<<"5 ";
                break;
            case 5 :
                cout<<"6 ";
                break;
            case 6 :
                cout<<"7 ";
                break;
            case 7 :
                cout<<"8 ";
                break;
            case 8 :
                cout<<"9 ";
                break;
            case 9 :
                cout<<"10 ";
                break;
            case 10 :
                cout<<"Jack ";
                break;
            case 11 :
                cout<<"Queen ";
                break;
            case 12 :
                cout<<"King ";
                break;
        }
        switch(logoArray[i])
        {
            case -1:
                break;
            case 0:
                cout<<"Diamond  ";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout<<"Club     ";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Heart    ";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"Spade    ";
                break;  
        }   
    }
}
void showCard (int playerInput, int player1Number, int player1Logo, int player2Number, int player2Logo)
{
    if(playerInput == 1)
    {
        cout<<"Player1 (You):"<<endl;
        printCard(player1Number, player1Logo);
        cout<<"Player2 (Computer):"<<endl;
        printCard(player2Number, player2Logo);
    }
    else if(playerInput == 2)
    {
        cout<<"Player1 (Computer):"<<endl;
        printCard(player1Number, player1Logo);
        cout<<"Player2 (You):"<<endl;
        printCard(player2Number, player2Logo);
    }
}
```

Honestly, i still newbie at programming. So i didn't know that i can't return a whole array from a function. After searching for clue, i found out that i can use pointer to return an array from function. When i try to fix the code, this error come out and i didn't know what i need to fix. 
The error keep appearing when i try to use the array from the function parameter,such as this

```
if(player1Number[i] == player2Number[j])<br/>
```

from function

`int** compareCard(int player1Number, int player1Logo, int player2Number, 
     int player2Logo, int cardInfo)`

and onward.

Can someone help me figure this out? Correction to the code would be very appreciated. Thankyou very much! (Sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: As the error says you’re trying to use an integer variable as an array. What should it do?

Comment: `int printResult (int playerNumber)` -> `playerNumber` has type of `int` not an `array of int` -> `if(playerNumber[i] == -1) break;` is invalid. So are many others.

Comment: You'd fix many of your errors if you added some type aliases and used them consistently, `using hand = std::array<int, 5>; using deck = std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 13>;`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thankyou for the hint. i need to re-declare the paramater as an array when implementing the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `compareCard` with a bunch of arrays (so int pointers) as parameters:

```
int* compareCard(int[5], int[5], int[5], int[5], int[13][4]);
```

Then, however, you're implementing it using integers (not pointers) as parameters:

```
int** compareCard(int player1Number, int player1Logo, int player2Number, int player2Logo, int cardInfo)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++)
```

You're also using them as arrays:

```
if(player1Logo[i] < player2Logo[j]) cardInfo[player1Number[i]][player1Logo[i]] = -1;
```

Also, the return type is wrong. You're declaring it as `int*`, but then implement it as `int**`. You have to ensure that the signature of your function matches. It looks like taking the signature of the declaration and applying it to the definition should fix this compile time error.

Does your compiler issue any warnings for these function declarations? If not, see if you can set it to be more strict with warnings. Getting the correct warnings for potential errors greatly increases debug efficiency.

Comment: thankyou for the respond! i forget to declare the parameters as an array, maybe thinking how to pass an array make me tired and a bit careless. Thankyou so much for the solution!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Comment: i'm sorry, but if you don't mind can you help 1 more time? i already corrected my code and there is only one error left which is "cannot convert 'int(*)[4]' to 'int **' in return". This error is from return cardInfo from compareCard function

Comment: In that function you're returning a pointer to the whole `cardInfo` 2D array, I think this isn't what you intended.

Comment: i want to return the 2D array of cardInfo. is there any way to return 2D array from function? i think it works the same as 1D array, but apparently it didn't work.

Comment: It does work similarly, but then you have another level of indirection, because a 2D array is represented by `int**` and a 1D array by `int*`.